# How to filter by workflow id and name in oozie web console?

Tags: oozie

In *oozie Web Console*, there is an option called **Custom Filter**. Please let me know how to use custom filter to filter by Workflow ID or Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy. Just do like this.

**custom filter workflow id**
[image]

**custom filter coordinator id**
[image]

filtering by name is same pattern. :)

**append)** multi filter condition.
[image]

Comment: thanks for the details. Do you know whether Filtering by name support regular expression (regex)?

Comment: I'm sorry. but I guess...not support regular expression. but I tested, multi filter condition. like 'status=SUCCEEDED;user=xxx' :)

Answer (score 0):

- To filter by workflow or Coordinator Id, Custom Filter -> **id=<workflow/coord_id>**
- To filter by Workflow Name, Custom Filter -> **name=<workflow_name>**